# Passing variable json array value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Hi Sorry for the title I really don't know where to start, I just want to pass my variable in a JSON array value if that what's called.. Im just gonna explain with code

So basically this is my variable, Inside of this variable is dynamically change depends on the API request

```
$scope.sampleConfig.default_sale_tax_code <-- Example inside of this variable is OUTPUT
```

Now I have this function that will is full of json arry too using `_.map($scope.taxCode, sampleFunction)` map in lodash

```
function sampleFunction(value) {
            var sample = $scope.sampleConfig.default_sale_tax_code;
            $scope.sampleASD = value,sample
            console.log($scope.sampleASD)
        }
```

Now my question is how can i put my variable to the `value.(put variable here)` I tried the following...

```
 $scope.sampleASD = value,sample <-- it just return all the datas
 $scope.sampleASD = value.sample < --- it just return undefined
 $scope.sampleASD = value  + sample <-- it just return an [object object]OUTPUT... OUTPUT is the variable string inside of my $scope.sampleConfig.default_sale_tax_code
```

Comment: Instead of `$scope.sampleASD = value,sample`, why not do `$scope.sampleASD = [value,sample]`?

Comment: it just add in the the variable to the array.. I want something like value.OUTPUT but im getting [obj obj] OUTPUT when i put my variable next to the value

Comment: sorry for not making it clear